# Is there a way to use an array on a curved surface, like roof tiles on a curved roof?

Tags: modifiers

I want to use an array like the one shown on the bottom roofs on the top curved roof, to make my roof tiles.[image]

Comment: Try using the shrinkwrap modifier below the array modifier

Comment: Is their a way to do that while using the displacement modifier with cloud texture technique for an uneven affect?

Comment: Yes! Just make sure your displacement is put before the shrinkwrap modifier. It will follow the modifier geometry.

Comment: if you don't need a close-up shot you could also use a Normal map with the tile pattern